# How can I make Vim's `J` and `gq` commands use one space after a period?

Tags: vim, formatting

When I use Vim's `J` command, most lines are joined with a single space for padding. But after a period Vim always uses two spaces. Take the following example:

```
This ends with a comma,
but this ends with a period.
Join with 'J' and what do you get?
```

For me, the result is:

```
This ends with a comma, but this ends with a period.  Join with 'J' and what do you get?
```

One space after the comma, two after the period. Same story if you reformat the paragraph with the `gq` command.

Is there a setting that I can modify to make Vim use only one space after the period?

Comment: Does anyone understand the rationale for this default?

Comment: @CiroSantilli http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing

Comment: @DenilsonSá: tldr; putting two spaces between sentences used to be considered best practise, and it still is by some people.

Comment: @Flimm From the point of typography, putting two spaces is a bad practice. However, this can give your text editor some additional hints about how to proceed the text.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆再教育营六四事件法轮功郝海东 This can give your text editor some additional hints about how to proceed the text. Emacs, for example, **requires** two spaces.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
:help joinspaces


'joinspaces' 'js'    boolean    (default on)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    Insert two spaces after a '.', '?' and '!' with a join command.
    When 'cpoptions' includes the 'j' flag, only do this after a '.'.
    Otherwise only one space is inserted.
    NOTE: This option is set when 'compatible' is set.
```

So, you would do a

```
:set nojoinspaces
```

to obtain what you desire.

Alternatively, you can toggle the setting with

```
:set joinspaces!
```

Answer (score 30):

You need to `:set nojoinspaces` to get rid of the double space.  [Documentation here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27joinspaces%27)

Comment: Or in .vimrc: omit the leading colon: `set nojoinspaces`

Answer (score 12):

```
:h 'joinspaces'
```

Set this option to 0/false/no.